# Error when I am trying to establishing a client and server connection using SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr

I am trying to create a server client communication using **SignalR**. I have manage to perform that communication locally. My server side code is the following:

```
    class Program
{
    static private IDisposable SignalR { get; set; }
    const string ServerURI = "http://localhost:1234";
    private static IHubProxy HubProxy { get; set; }
    private static HubConnection Connection { get; set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SignalR = WebApp.Start(ServerURI);
        Console.WriteLine("Server running at " + ServerURI);

        Connection = new HubConnection(ServerURI);
        HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
        HubProxy.On<string, string>("SendMessage", (name, message) => Console.WriteLine(name + ":" + message));
        Connection.Start().Wait();

        string messageToSentToClients;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type someting to send to clients and press enter");
            messageToSentToClients = Console.ReadLine();
           HubProxy.Invoke("Send", "Server", messageToSentToClients);
       } while (messageToSentToClients != "exit");

   }
}

public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message) { Clients.All.sendMessage(name, message); }
}

class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) { app.MapSignalR(); }
}
```

The code is working with clients which located in the same mahcine. I want to work with clients in the same lan however not in the same machine. What should I replace in the case of ServerURI in order to be able to work with clients which are not in the same machine? How can I put the ip of the machine since when I am tried the following I failed:

```
const string ServerURI = "http://ip:port";
```

and I got the following message from the line `SignalR = WebApp.Start(ServerURI);`:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're hosting SignalR on a server somewhere, you'd use the hostname/IP address of the server and the port that it's configured to be listening to for this.

Unfortunately, without additional information about what exactly threw the exception, it's hard to give much additional help.

Comment: this is my server side code which sends message to clients. I am wandering how can I change the ServerURI not to be localhost but the machine's ip.

Comment: The exception I am receiving is in the question.